# Split file in linux based on content and no of lines

Tags: linux, file, split, command

I have text file like this which has more than 12 million lines.

```
22 start of first batch
33 some more text 2
55 some data 1
66 more data 1
55 some data 2
66 more data 2
99 end of first batch
...
22 start of Nth batch
33 some more text N
55 some data N
66 more data N
55 some data N
66 more data N
99 end of Nth batch
```

In this text file, there are multiple batches. Each batch further has multiple transactions inside it. Last transaction being 99 for each batch.
I want to split this file into multiple files with following limitations:

> 1. Each file can should contain around 100,000 records.
> 2. Each file should contain complete details of batches. For example if in one file we have already added 100,000 lines, but still the last line inserted does not start with 99, then we continue inserting in that same file till we get 99.

Can this be done in linux in a single line command ?

Comment: Other than with `csplit`?

Comment: Use awk.  Store the output file name in a variable.  Write output and count the lines.  When you match `^99` and have output over 100,000 lines, increment a counter in the output file name.

Comment: Why the focus on a one liner? I think a nice little script in your preferred language is written down much quicker; and will be easier to read and maintain ... what is the point of a 300 column complicated one-liner that nobody understands 3 minutes after writing it down?

Comment: I am trying to call this linux command from java. File splitting in java will be too time consuming. So I have a java code that will first split the file by running a system command and then process each file parallely. Thats why I was thinking of doing this in one line. not sure if any other way is there or not.

Comment: "File splitting in java will be too time consuming." Then you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams  you are right. I used simple java code to split a  file with 7 million lines and it took only 2 seconds. My understanding was unix is good for file processing and splitting, so I was thinking of unix a unix command in my java code. I guess I should have at least tried it once with java.